# create a button to add friends to a circle on Google Plus

Tags: html, api, google-plus

in my google account I have created a circle called test and I have an HTML page called "zone" and my idea is to create a button that says "circle test" so that when my friends  agregen automatically  pressured the button to that circle.
Can I make this?
  and if possible
How could she do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is no way to Add to a Circle from the Google+ Platform API. However, [that feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=47) is in our Google+ Platform Issue Tracker. If you Star the issue, you will get an email for all future updates.